# I can't extract 2 records from the database, using 2 different queries. Only one is given as output in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 different MySQL queries. Both of them give result in PHPMYADMIN, but only one gives result in my PHP page.

Each query checks the form data (user and password and a variable called "$dest"). One query validates a certain user and one query validates the admin. I want that if the user/admin data exist in the database, they both can enter the php page to upload a file in a form.

```
    include('../PHP/connection.php'); 
   include('../PHP/connection_achizitii.php');
    include('../PHP/connection_sapl.php'); 
    include('../PHP/connection_contab.php');
        $dest = $_SESSION['dest'];
        
        //data from form
        $form_user = $_POST['usr'];
        $form_pass = $_POST['pswd'];
    
    //This displays correctly the form data
    echo 'Form data: Dest: '.$dest.' user: '.$form_user.' pass: '.$form_pass.'<br>'; 
    
    /*My 1st query (gives result in phpmyadmin, in "SQL query section", but NO RESULT in PHP page)*/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `logtoforms` WHERE `compart`='$dest'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    
    $user_db = $record['user_db'];
    $pass_db = $record['pass_db'];

    //My 2nd query (gives result in phpmyadmin, in "SQL query section", also in PHP page)
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `logtoforms` WHERE `compart`='admin'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    $record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    
    $user_adm = $record2['user_db'];
    $pass_adm = $record2['pass_db'];

To test my 2 queries:

    echo "Dest = $dest <br>"; //OK
    echo "From form: user: $form_user ; pass: $form_pass <br>"; //OK
    echo "Din BD: user: $user_db ; pass: $pass_db <br>"; // EMPTY RESULT
    echo "Din BD: user_admin: $user_adm ; pass_admin: $pass_adm <br>"; //OK
```

---

**Yes, $dest comes with a value from the page where the login form exists. It is a $_SESSION variable so I can access it in another 2 pages.**

Comment: Do a `var_dump($dest);`, and check what length that reports.

Comment: Is $dest populated with a value?

Comment: You should have a read of [this](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) and make sure your connection is set up properly. Try `var_dump($sql, $record, $sql2, $record2);`. You should be using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) whenever passing variables into your queries, with the exception of identifiers, which should be tested against whitelists.

Comment: @Mathias Hillmann Yes, $dest comes with a value from the same page where user enters username and password. It is a $_SESSION variable so I can have access to it in other pages too

Comment: I did a var_dump($dest); It returns a STRING (which indeed it is correct; $dest must contain a string)
string(9) "comercial"

Comment: What does `$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM 'logtoforms' WHERE 'compart'='comercial'";` return from the second query?

Comment: OK, I tried:
 
var_dump($sql);
Result: string(54) "SELECT * FROM `logtoforms` WHERE `compart`='comercial'"

var_dump($record);
Result: NULL

var_dump($sql2);
Result: string(50) "SELECT * FROM `logtoforms` WHERE `compart`='admin'"

var_dump($record2);
Result: OK, it gives admin username and password

Comment: I realised now that both queries (for USER's and for ADMIN's username and password) looks in the wrong database. It looks in the last "include file", which is include('../PHP/connection_contab.php'); Instead, it should look in the include('../PHP/connection.php'); 
I have few databases, and each has a table with users and admin. So I want that the query to look in the right "include connection file". Shall I make a separate database with all users and the admin for all the databases and then include only 1 connection file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now!
Thank you, user **user1191247** for the idea.
Doing the `var_dump($sql, $record, $sql2, $record2);` I saw that my 1st query looks into database x, and my 2nd query looks into my database y.

I mean I have a user table (containing admin user too) for each database. Now that I put together into one database the users+the admin table, my queries know where to validate the users.

```
 include('../PHP/connection.php'); 
 include('../PHP/connection_achizitii.php');
 include('../PHP/connection_sapl.php'); 
 include('../PHP/connection_contab.php'); /*my both queries looked for the user and for the admin here only, in this connection to database x, but my queries must have looked into the database with this connection include('../PHP/connection.php'); */
```

Each of my databases: **primarialugoj_ro, achizitii, contab, sapl** contained a table "logtoforms" with users and passwords and values for $dest variable. The **admin** user (with it's corresponding password) was the common username used in all "logtoforms" tables.

My problem was that only my 2nd query found the admin user:

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `logtoforms` WHERE `compart`='admin'";
```

It found the admin user into the **contab** database (the last included file):

```
include('../PHP/connection_contab.php');
```

My 2nd query seemed to search also in the last database (the last included file):

```
include('../PHP/connection_contab.php');
```

instead of finding my user in the first database (called **primarialugoj_ro**) which connection to it was made in the first included file:

```
include('../PHP/connection.php');
```

Now I have all the users (from all databases) + the admin user into one database (**primarialugoj_ro**) so I use only this file, in all my php pages, to connect to this database: ***connection.php***

[image]